# test kitchen salt_solo passing in variables from platforms

Tags: salt-stack, test-kitchen

I am running test kitchen with salt using `salt_solo` and I cannot pass variables into the formula if I declare them in the platform.

For example if this was my `.kitchen.yml`

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    grains:
      org:
        bat: batz

suites:
  - name: binary
    provisioner:
      name: salt_solo
      state_top:
        base:
          '*':
            - binary
      formula: binary
      grains:
        org:
          foo: bar
```

Then my formula is not able to access `{{grains['org']['bat']}}`, but it is able to access `{{grains['org']['foo']}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `provisioner:` before the platform variables.  This fix to the example `.kitchen.yml` from above will solve the issue:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    provisioner:
      grains:
        org:
          bat: batz

suites:
  - name: binary
    provisioner:
      name: salt_solo
      state_top:
        base:
          '*':
            - binary
      formula: binary
      grains:
        org:
          foo: bar
```